# Format of File using Awk in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, awk

All I did was ls to a file, then ran a simple awk print. I'm new to both PowerShell and Awk, but the output is obviously not what's expected. Can anyone explain this? Does it have something to do with the format of the file?

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\lmoser\My Documents\Test> awk '{ print }' lsfiles.txt > awkedlsfile.txt
PS C:\Documents and Settings\lmoser\My Documents\Test> cat lsfiles.txt
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file1.txt
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file2.txt
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file3.txt
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file4.txt
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file5.txt
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file6.txt
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM       2164 lsfiles.txt
PS C:\Documents and Settings\lmoser\My Documents\Test> cat awkedlsfile.txt
----                -------------     ------ ----
??????        ? ????  ?  ? ??? ??            ?????????
??
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file2.txt
??????        ? ????  ?  ? ??? ??            ?????????
??
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file4.txt
??????        ? ????  ?  ? ??? ??            ?????????
??
-a---         10/8/2009  10:32 AM          0 file6.txt
??????        ? ????  ?  ? ??? ??       ???? ???????????
??
?
```

Comment: Which awk.exe are you using?  I can get MKS Toolkit awk to work fine from PowerShell given your example.  However I can't get cygwin awk to work at all from PowerShell.  Works fine from the cygwin bash shell.

Comment: why do you want to use awk from powershell?

Comment: Why would you not use awk from powershell?  Just because cygwin is supposed to be great?  Or is there something deeper here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your awk unicode-aware?  I suspect not.  If that is the case try this:

```
awk '{ print }' lsfiles.txt | Out-File awkedlsfile.txt -encoding ASCII
```

By default, PowerShell redirects to file using Unicode format.  Essentially using ">" is just a shortcut for "| Out-File {path} -Encoding Unicode"

Comment: Basically the right idea.  I piped the original ls to an ASCII encoded file, then awk worked as expected.